# No Voltage in a Circuit but still a Current, How?

Tags: electric-circuits

Hi I've done an experiment in physics using a basic circuit. Can anybody explain how come the data logging equipment I was using continued to register a current when there isn't a positvie voltage in the circuit.

Comment: What Is that "basic circuit"? Sigh.

Comment: How much of a current are you measuring?  Is it just (60 Hz) noise?

Comment: You may think there is zero volts in a circuit when in fact there is a finite small value. How large was the current registered?

Comment: You found superconductivity at room-temperatures... I would by a ticket to Stockholm...

Answer (score 3):

If you have a short circuit you may have just few millivolts, and still a significant current.

Another option - when measuring voltage you probably not connected ground properly of your voltmeter.

And finally, small current might be just calibration error.